# How to protect/encrypt my assets in Cocos2d-X?

Tags: encryption, cocos2d-x, assets

I am finishing a Tower Defense game that will be published to Apple Store and Google Play. The project is built in Cocos2d-X and I am afraid about the protection of my assets. So, I would like to know if there is any option/feature in Cocos2d-X to allow encryption?

I found that TexturePacker provides encryption for Cocos2d, but I have not seen any similar option for Cocos2d-X.

Please I need help for some one that already have implemented such a task.

Comment: how much memory and CPU usage, preprocessing and load time are you willing to sacrifice for the perception of protection? Your option is to use TP because then you get a decent protection for free essentially, or rename the image file extensions to ward off 99% of the curious users. But what are you really afraid of? If someone is illegally using your graphics in another app, you should drag them to court. At the least you can get the platform holder to remove their app, It helps if you watermark specific assets to prove your rightful ownership .. err copyright. Encryption ... not helping much

Comment: Thanks for your valued information, I am seriously considering the renaming as alternative. If you remember what happened when Kingdom Rush was plagiarized with all its graphics and sounds effects? that kind of things can damage really bad to any small indie developer. Also I would like to ask you, have you ever used TP encryption on any of your projects? what kind of side effect do you noticed in terms of performance ?

Comment: no idea, never used it, never going to. If you get plagiarised you should feel happy actually. 99.9% of devs never get that honor and the free marketing buzz surrounding that (if you manage to play it well).

Comment: keep in mind: anyone can take screenshots of your app and make cutouts of your graphics, and it's probably easier to automate that than to overcome any kind of image encryption

Comment: I totally agree with you, definitely you cleared up all my doubts, thanks a lot.